# Free/ Open Source/ Cheap: Lean & light way to Backup & Restore few INI/ CFG files?

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, backup, configuration-management

I do not intend to run major backup processes for lot of heavy files here so need something super light & lean that can run in background without much memory or CPU cycles.

I'd like for it to backup/ snapshot some INI/ CFG files of few tiny utility Programs who end up trashing their INI/ CFG files now and then and I'd like to be able to go back & restore to previous or saved states of those.

Thoughts & suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about writing a script file that makes archives of the files every few hours (or whenever), having it run at startup, make archives, and sleep a few hours should work.

I don't know much windows scripting (batch file), but zip or 7zip programs should have command line interfaces to archive files & save the archive somewhere. Restoring from a zip/7z file should be quick & easy too. Naming it with the current date-time should avoid overlaps.

If you've got Cygwin or the new "Ubuntu for Windows" thing, you could use a bash script & commands like `while true do`, `sleep 2h`, `filename-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M")`

There are probably large backup programs that could do it automatically, but I'm sure they wouldn't be as "lean & light" as a script file & `sleep` command. (almost didn't answer, but since you asked for *"Thoughts & suggestions"*...)